# C++ Exception Handling - Concrete Example

Tags: c++, exception

I've this program (parts of program not posted):

```
//Includes and functions
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream loc("achievements.loc", ios::binary);

    getline(loc, header, static_cast<char>(1));

    loc.seekg(15, ios::cur);

    loc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&subdirs), sizeof(subdirs));



    for( int i = 0; i < nstrings; i++ )
    {
        loc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&strid), sizeof(strid));

        loc.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&stroffset), sizeof(stroffset));

        curoffset = loc.tellg();
        loc.seekg(strcodesbeg+16+stroffset);

        getline(loc, codestring, '\0');

        loc.seekg(curoffset);

    }

}
```

I want to terminate the program if:
- The file is not opened;
- The header string, obtained by getline isn't equal to "String";
- Any of the read function fails;
- Any of the seekg fails;
- The strid, doesn't match with 1234.

How can I do this using C++ Exceptions? Should I use a single `try{}catch(...){}` block, creating functions that, for example, reads the data and sends `EOF_REACHED` on failure, or a `try{}catch(var e){}catch(var2 e){}`, a `class`, or any other way?

I understand the concept of the exceptions in simple function, but it gets complicated when there's a bigger program.

I didn't found too any c++ source code that uses try catch block explicitly in the main function, but works with exceptions. How this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The most verbose way to do this is to subclass a particular exception that will give you some context about what happened, for instance:

```
class FileNotOpenedException : public std::runtime_error {};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   try
   {
      ifstream loc("achievements.loc", ios::binary);

      if(!loc.is_open())
         throw FileNotOpenedException;

      // ...
   }
   catch(const FileNotOpenedException& e)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Note, however that using exceptions for expected error conditions is not necessarily good practice.  Exceptions should be used only for truly "exceptional" conditions, that is something that is completely unexpected in your program, that you have no way of recovering from in the particular scope.  The file not being opened above is a bad example.  One of the `read()` or `seekg()` functions failing however may be more appropriate.

That said, it is possible to do what you are asking, and above is an example of one way to do it.

Comment: You said that using exceptions is a good practice only in read() and seekg() right? How should I do that checking? And without using exceptions, how I terminate the program if I can't open the file? I could use abort() or exit(), but this is a bad practice too, right?

Comment: -1 The advice given about when to use exceptions is utterly wrongheaded, leading readers astray. For "something that is completely unexpected", `assert`. Or just `abort`. Perhaps after logging.

Comment: In the simple example, you would advocate using an exception if the file wasn't opened then?  Something that could be handled with a simple `if` check, and dealt with immediately (logged)?  That is wrong headed.  Perhaps you aren't tasked with writing a lot of time-critical low latency software?